# Best way to migrate old Ubuntu Server?

Tags: rsync, migration, hyper-v, 8.04

I need to get Ubuntu 8.04 Server(running on XenServer by hosting service) to Hyper-V(Onpremise, hosted by us) this weekend.

I was planning to follow [this](https://lowendbox.com/blog/how-to-migrate-a-hosted-server-in-5-easy-steps-with-rsync/) guide. But should I first install Ubuntu 8.04 Server to Hyper-V, then migrate and upgrade to newer/supported release or should I install latest Ubuntu Server(probably 18.04.4 LTS) on Hyper-V and migrate 8.04 straight to that?

Thanks for possible help :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is no supported upgrade path for that prehistoric version.  Backup, install new supported version, and reload.

Comment: Release-upgrading *five* times in a row, three of which are EOL and no longer easily available, seems like a waste of an entire day (or two).

Comment: That makes sense, didn't think about that. Does it matter which LTS release I choose(14.04/16.04/18.04), if thinking about compatibility with 8.04? @OrganicMarble "and reload", do you mean reboot or is reload a Linux function?

Comment: I meant reload your backups.